# Trouble returning result when I make use of promise

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, promise, request, cheerio

I've created a script in `node` using `promise` in combination with `cheerio` to parse the `links` to the titles of different posts from a website and then scrape the `title` of each post from it's inner page by reusing those `links`.

My current script can fetch them accordingly If I uncomment this line `console.log($("h1 > a").eq(0).text());` within `getData`. However, it appears that the second function still doesn't return anything.

> How can I make the script run successfully the way it is now?

I've written so far:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';
const base_link = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

const items = [];
const titles = [];

let getLinks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('.summary').each(function() {
                items.push(base_link + $(this).find(".question-hyperlink").attr("href"));
            });
            resolve(items);
        });
    });
};

let getData = (links) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let nurl of links) {
            request(nurl, function(error, response, html) {
                let $ = cheerio.load(html);
                titles.push($("h1 > a").eq(0).text())
                // console.log($("h1 > a").eq(0).text());

            });
            resolve(titles);
        }
    });
};

getLinks().then((resultList) => {
    return getData(resultList)
})
```

Upon executiing the above script, I get no result, no error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that `request` is async so you will see the console logs when the callbacks are executed.

However, you are resolving the promise in the first iteration of your `for` loop. Therefore you return an empty array.

You would need to resolve the promise only when the last request has completed:

```
let getData = (links) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let count = 0
    for (let nurl of links) {
      request(nurl, function(error, response, html) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html);
        titles.push($("h1 > a").eq(0).text())

        count++ // increment count
        if (count === links.length) {
          resolve(titles); // resolve if last request to complete
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Alternatively, you could try wrapping each request in a promise and then using `Promise.all()`, which resolves with an array of results when all promises have completed:

```
let getData = (links) => {
  const promises = links
    .map(nurl => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(nurl, function(error, response, html) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html);
        resolve($("h1 > a").eq(0).text())
      })
    }))

  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Steve Holgado. I just executed the script after rectifying your suggested portion within it but I still get nothing as output. Thanks.

Comment: When you say *output*, do you mean something like `getData(resultList).then(data => console.log(data))`?

Comment: Perfect!! Yes, that is what I meant @Steve Holgado.

Comment: Glad it has helped :)